# Fixed width div at left and fluid width div on the right

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, css-float

I want to have a fixed width `<div>` on the left, and a flexible `<div>` on the right for when the window resizes. **Also**, The left `<div>` is collapsible (I use jQuery to hide it with negative margin), Then I need the right `<div>` to have the full width.

PS: I'm not being able to have a 100% width div inside a container with padding without having horizontal scrolls...

Comment: Can you provide your code?  HTML and CSS to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to have a fixed width  on
>   the left, and a flexible  on the
>   right for when the window resizes.

`float: left` only the left `div`, and add `overflow: hidden` to the right `div`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/JsLuG/

> Also, The left  is collapsible (I
>   use jQuery to hide it with negative
>   margin), Then I need the right 
>   to have the full width.

That works with my method: http://jsfiddle.net/JsLuG/1/

> PS: I'm not being able to have a 100%
>   width div inside a container with
>   padding without having horizontal
>   scrolls...

That's because `width: 100%` does not include `padding`.

See: http://css-tricks.com/2841-the-css-box-model/

The simplest way to work around this is to not declare `width: 100%`. A block-level element will default to taking the "full width" (`width: auto`).

Or, add a wrapper element and put the `padding` on that. Or, use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: That's really interesting, I did not expect `overflow: hidden` to change the way the div positions itself. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Looks like `overflow: auto` works too, but not `overflow: visible`.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` forces the creation of a new "block formatting context". This article explains it: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Comment: Really interesting use of the overflow, plus answered all of the questions

Answer (score 3):

Just set the margin-left of the right div to be the width of the left div. When you run the script to collapse the left-div you'll have to adjust the right-div's margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/vpKfn/

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for using `postion:fixed;` The example below will get you started. you could easily make different classes for when the sidebar is hidden and just switch out the classes on the divs to use different position values.

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">side stuff</div>
<div class="main">main content</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar{
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:150px;
}

.main{
    background-color:#AAA;
    position:fixed;
    left:150px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0; 
}
```